# How to Correlate an Object ID from Activity Log to a User, SPN Claim or UPN Claim

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Looking through my Azure Audit Logs and see someone deleted a bunch of services.   I see under "Initiated by" is a Object ID (GUID).  Documentation says this is also refered to in JSON as “caller”.

caller:     Email address of the user who has performed the operation, UPN claim, or SPN claim based on availability.

So have now tried these AZ CLI commands with no luck:

Looking for a USER

```
sdistefa@Azure:~$ az ad user show --upn-or-object-id 5e9a4129-c335-4dcb-84d0-488531e7b026
```

But get:

```
Resource '5e9a4129-c335-4dcb-84d0-488531e7b026' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
```

Looking for a Service Principal:

```
sdistefa@Azure:~$ az ad sp list --subscription 9350e6db-d02d-4db7-baee-76f9498dfd13 --spn 5e9a4129-c335-4dcb-84d0-488531e7b026
[]
```

I need to figure out how to query for a UPN Claim or a Service Principal Claim…… I guess?

I switched to Powershell.  I queried myself to see my ObjectId and then tried the command to find myself by a valid ID.   PS Azure:> Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "sdistefa@itron.com"

ObjectId                             DisplayName      UserPrincipalName  UserType
--------                             -----------      -----------------  --------
f9f1560e-ecba-461d-a811-c0f923a7895a DiStefano, Steve sdistefa@itron.com Member
Azure:/
PS Azure:> Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId -objectid f9f1560e-ecba-461d-a811-c0f923a7895a

ObjectId                             DisplayName      UserPrincipalName  UserType
--------                             -----------      -----------------  --------
f9f1560e-ecba-461d-a811-c0f923a7895a DiStefano, Steve sdistefa@itron.com Member

Now I try the ObjectId from the activity Log:   and it returns a blank:
Azure:/
PS Azure:> Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId -objectid 5e9a4129-c335-4dcb-84d0-488531e7b026
Azure:/
PS Azure:>

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an ID to the -spn flag with your command `az ad sp list` however that spn stands for "service principal name" since you're dealing with an id here you'd be better off using [az ad sp show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-show) and use the `-id` flag:

`az ad sp show --id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

Comment: Says "resource '5e....' does not exist or one of its queried rference-property objects are not present."

Comment: Can you confirm that the Id you’re supplying is definitely the objectid and not the application (client id) of the principal you’re querying for? And that’s you’re looking for a service principal (called an Enterprise Application the Azure Portal) and not an Application Registration

Comment: This GUID appears  in the Azure Activity Log. The JSON Tab shows this same GUID labeled "Caller".   I read the Azure docs and its says:
caller: Email address of the user who has performed the operation, UPN claim, or SPN claim based on availability.

So I really don't know which of the three I am looking for here.   This is the problem.  Whatever it is deleted a bunch or resources.   I was thinking maybe its a user no longer with the company?   This thinking it was a SP from a "delete RG" Action, but I see the CLAIM after UPN and SPN above.     So to me, this is not very easy to understand.

Comment: Yes, it could be a principal - either service or user - which has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell, this is what i do:

```
$valid_email_regex = '^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$'

if ($activityLogs.Caller -match $valid_email_regex) {
  $resourceLogs["event_initiated_by"] = $activityLogs.Caller
}
else {
  $resourceLogs["event_initiated_by"] = "{0} ({1})" -f (Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $activityLogs.Caller).DisplayName, $activityLogs.Caller
}
```

If it's not an e-mail, it's an ObjectId, so I use "Get-AzADServicePrincipal" to retrieve the DisplayName (using the ObjectId indeed). Then I format the result to add the ObjectId in parenthesis after the DisplayName.

So the main command to reply to your question is:

```
(Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ObjectId ***************).DisplayName
```